# Pre-checked checkbox in Bootbox

Tags: bootbox

I'm using Bootbox and want to have one of the check boxes pre-selected. For example:

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'What would you like on your pizza?',
    inputType: 'checkbox',
    inputOptions: [
        {
            text: 'pepperoni',
            value: '1',
        },
        {
            text: 'mushrooms',
            value: '2',
        },
        {
            text: 'onions',
            value: '3',
        }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    };
```

Lets say that I want to have the first item in the array, which is pepperoni, selected as a default. Is it possible to do this using Bootbox? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bootbox has a value option for prompt. http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#prompt-dialog-options

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes, I noticed that but the value option doesn't seem to be what I need in order to have the element pre-checked.

Comment: It is the only option Bootbox provides. You just need to make sure that the types match; so, `value: '1'`, not `value: 1`.

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes, `value: '1'` is exactly what I have in my code.

Comment: What version of Bootbox? It works fine when I add that to an example, using 4.4: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/315546/

Comment: I'm using 4.4 as well. Unfortunately I can't open js fiddle here. So with your code, are you getting a pre-checked checkbox?

Comment: Yes. All I did was add the value option to the example code for a checkbox input.

Comment: Ok I see. I think there is some confusion. I'm getting the checkbox just fine, thats not what I need. I need the checkbox to already have a checkmark in it when the prompt pops up.

Comment: Yes, I got that. The first option is checked, in that fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `value` option to prompt.

For a single checked option (https://jsfiddle.net/j7wgncsf/):

```js
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'What would you like on your pizza?',
    inputType: 'checkbox',
    value: '1', // <----- this
    inputOptions: [
        {
            text: 'pepperoni',
            value: '1',
        },
        {
            text: 'mushrooms',
            value: '2',
        },
        {
            text: 'onions',
            value: '3',
        }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Or, to have multiple options checked, use an array (https://jsfiddle.net/yasok05p/):

```js
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'What would you like on your pizza?',
    inputType: 'checkbox',
    value: ['1', '2'],// <----- this
    inputOptions: [
        {
            text: 'pepperoni',
            value: '1',
        },
        {
            text: 'mushrooms',
            value: '2',
        },
        {
            text: 'onions',
            value: '3',
        }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tieson T.! Sorry, I don't have access to js fiddle where I work so couldn't see what you did. Thanks again.